# Is there a way to make dummy variables that also count the number of occurances?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I was trying to create columns that can record the number of occurrences of a letter.
For example if i had a list '''['A','B','AA','AB','ABB']'''

I would get an output

```
      A   |   B
   ---------------         
      1   |   0
      0   |   1 
      2   |   0 
      1   |   1 
      1   |   2
```

In the end i want to be able to concat this to a pandas DataFrame for more comparisons. So far I've managed to generate the columns correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to put in the entries.

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import collections 

C_det=pd.DataFrame(['A','B','AA','BB','ABB'],columns=['C_Dk'])
inc=0
Temp_cab=pd.DataFrame()
T_C=pd.DataFrame()

for c in C_det['C_Dk']:    
    inc+=1
    c_d=dict(collections.Counter(c))
    print(c_d)        
    for i in c_d.items():       
        T_C[i[0]]=i[1] 
    c_d.clear()    

print(T_C)    

    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `Counter` for list of `dict`s, pass to `DataFrame` constructor and replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with casting to integers by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in C_det['C_Dk']]).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  2  0
3  0  2
4  1  2
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Wouldn't have thought to use list comprehension in a Data-frame.